# Method calling using reference variable

Tags: java, constructor, overriding, chaining

```
public class Base {

    int var =0;
    Base(){
        System.out.println("Inside Base constructor .....");
        setVar();
    }

    public void setVar(){
        System.out.println("Inside base setVar method.....");
        var+=10;
    }

    public int getVar(){
        return var;
    }
}
```

Derived Class:

```
public class Derived extends Base {

    Derived(){
        System.out.println("Inside Derived constructor .....");
        setVar();
    }

    public void setVar(){
        System.out.println("Inside Derived setVar method.....");

        var+=20;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Base b = new Derived();
        System.out.println(b.getVar());
    }
}
```

Output.....

```
Inside Base constructor .....                                                      
Inside Derived setVar method.....                                                   
Inside Derived constructor .....                                                    
Inside Derived setVar method.....                                                   
40
```

Question ----> why when control goes to base class constructor , setVar() method of Derived class is called instead of Base class setVar() method.
I expected output as 30 , but when ran this program in debug mode found the flow and got output as 40. Could anyone please explain the logic behind this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java will decide which method to run based on the runtime type of the variable, i.e. use polymorphism, at all times, even if the method called is from a base class constructor.

When the base class constructor is called, polymorphism means that the derived class's version of `setVar` is called, and 20 is added.  Then the derived class constructor is called, and again the derived class's version of `setVar` is called, and 20 is added, again, yielding 40.

Comment: On your answer I have two doubts : 1>This means if in main method even if I change Base b = new Derived()   to    Derived d = new Derived() same thing will happen ??                                                                                           2> How to call Base class setVar() method using Derived class object ?

Comment: 1. Yes, only the runtime type matters.  2. From code calling the class's methods, the overridden method is inaccessible.  From code internal to the class, you can call `super.setVar();`.

Comment: "From code calling the class's methods, the overridden method is inaccessible."  Could you please elaborate this statement of yours ?

Comment: From code such as that in `main`, outside of the `Base` or `Derived` classes, you cannot call the overridden method.  `b.setVar()` will call the derived class's method, not the base class's method, if `b` is really a `Derived` at runtime, regardless of whether `b` is declared to be a `Base` or a `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism at work.

When you override a super class method in derived class, then always your overridden method in derived class is called when someone operates on any object of derived class, even if that someone is a super class.

so `Derived` `setVar()` is called twice because it is overridden in '`Derived`' and you tried to create an object of '`Derived`' class.